# Add scope variable to array and then stop data bind

Tags: angularjs

For reference, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6u3Gn/1/

I am playing around with angular and ran into a behavior that I can understand, but am not sure how to stop. I created a simple form for places and things, where you define a place, and then you can add things at that place. When the button to add a thing is clicked, it successfully adds the thing to the place:

```
$scope.addThing = function() {
    if ('things' in $scope.place) {
        $scope.place.things.push($scope.thing);
    } else {
        var things = [$scope.thing]
        $scope.place['things'] = thing;
    }
};
```

However, when I try to add another thing, the first one is still bound to $scope.thing, so the first one updates to be the exact same as the second thing I add.

How can I stop the 2 way data binding once the object in the array has been added? Is there a way to do so, or am I going about adding it to the array all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that was easy. Not exactly sure how I missed it but the right way to do this is to use angular.copy($scope.variable). Whoops!